# Access Node Request body as variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have a node js script that makes an ajax call to get some credentials and then I need to utilize values from that body later in my script but the object keeps erroring as empty.

I can't seem to figure out how to access the `newCredentials` variable elsewhere in the script.

Thanks for any help!

```
var request = require('request');

request('https://localhost/sse/credentials.php', function (error, response, data) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var newCredentials = data;
}
else {
    console.log("Failed to Retrieve Credentials");
}
});

//Rest of script here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your method is asynchronous, you can't expect to be able to access its results in a synchronous manner. Rather, you should utilize a continuation or callback function to continue your program once you get the result back.

It can be something as simple as this:

```
var request = require('request');

// Do something with these credentials
function doSomethingWithCredentials (credentials) {
  // ...
}

request('https://localhost/sse/credentials.php', function (error, response, data) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Continue your program with the new data
    doSomethingWithCredentials(data);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Failed to Retrieve Credentials");
  }
});
```

Comment: @Jason Glad I could help!